# Blocking printing - CSS, HTML, PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, printing

I keep PDF files on the server in the "uploads" folder.
By using the link I can view the PDF file.
So when you click on this link, it takes you to: **Website address/uploads/file.pdf** and this PDF file is displayed in your browser.

I would like to be able to block the possibility of printing these PDF files but I have no idea how to get it.

Comment: You can't. Anything that is sent to the browser can be downloaded one way or another, and therefore it can also be printed.

Comment: There is no way you can force people not to print what is on their screen.

Comment: even if these files are accessed through my website? I can't block printing for all subpages from index.php?

Comment: you can password protect the pdf files.